# Random walk nested for loop loops forever

Tags: c++

I tried to code some random walk algorithm to practice C++ and rogue like coding but my function loops forever and does not actually do anything. The "cout << before while << endl; cin.get and the other inside the loop are here for error checking and every time the error is at the for h loop, it clocks one of my core to 100% and does nothing. Can somebody help me please ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

#define MAP_WIDTH      64
#define MAP_HEIGHT     24
#define WALK_DIRECTION  4
#define TILE_FLOOR      0
#define TILE_WALL       1

using namespace std;

int MapArray[MAP_HEIGHT][MAP_WIDTH];
int StepCount = 0;
const int MaxStepCount = 60;
void SetWalls(void);
int GenerateRandom(int a);
void DrunkardsWalk(void);

int main(void){

    SetWalls();
    DrunkardsWalk();

    for(int h = 0; h < MAP_HEIGHT; h++){
        cout << endl;
        for(int w = 0; w < MAP_WIDTH; w++){
            switch(MapArray[h][w]){
                case TILE_WALL:
                cout << "#";
                break;

                case TILE_FLOOR:
                cout << ".";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void SetWalls(void){

    for(int h = 0; h < MAP_HEIGHT; h++){
        cout << endl;
        for(int w = 0; w < MAP_WIDTH; w++){
            MapArray[h][w] = TILE_WALL;
        }
    }
}

int GenerateRandom(int a){

    int b;
    srand(time(NULL));
    b = rand() % a;
    return b;
}

void DrunkardsWalk(void){

    int RandHeight = GenerateRandom(MAP_HEIGHT);
    int RandWidth = GenerateRandom(MAP_WIDTH);
    int RandDirection = GenerateRandom(WALK_DIRECTION);

    cout << "Before while" << endl;
    cin.get();
    while(StepCount != MaxStepCount){
        cout << "After while" << endl;
        cin.get();
        for(int h = 0; h < RandHeight; h++){
            cout << "For h" << endl;
            cin.get();
            for(int w = 0; w < RandWidth; w++){
                cout << "For w" << endl;
                cin.get();
                if(RandDirection == 1){
                    MapArray[h+1][w] = TILE_FLOOR;
                    StepCount++;
                }
               else if(RandDirection == 2){
                    MapArray[h-1][w] = TILE_FLOOR;
                    StepCount++;
                }
                else if(RandDirection == 3){
                    MapArray[h][w+1] = TILE_FLOOR;
                    StepCount++;
                }
                else if(RandDirection == 4){
                    MapArray[h][w-1] = TILE_FLOOR;
                    StepCount++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Reseeding the generator each time you want a random number ain't gonna end well. It will make the individual appear to be rather sober.

Comment: You need to check your math. `random_number % 4` does not give you `[1, 4]` but `[0, 3]`

Comment: You kind find these kind of mistakes by learning how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `srand(time(NULL));` only once for the whole execution. So move it outside your function and you could put it in `main()` like this:

```
// ..

int main(void){
    srand(time(NULL));
    //..

    return 0;
}

// ..

int GenerateRandom(int a){
    int b;
    b = rand() % a;
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help !

Answer (score 0):

The loop condition

```
while(StepCount != MaxStepCount)
```

is not a good idea if StepCount is incremented more than one at each loop iteration.

If you replace it by

```
while(StepCount < MaxStepCount)
```

It should terminate.

Consider using a debugger like gdb instead of having breakpoints with cin.get(). It is more efficient for the debug and you can ask for the value of your counter for each loop.

Comment: Thanks for the advice !